# C# Storing multiple Items in multiple arrays for comparison

Tags: c#, arrays, comparison

I have an application that reads File names and their equivalent Hash codes from an XML(After i have created the XML using the same application) and What i would like it to do is compare one XML (the files and their hash codes) to another XML(With possibly different files and hash codes). I'm trying to create a compare function so that i can compare the file names, first, between the two XMLs and then compare the Hash codes if the files exists in both XMLs.

(to help understand what im trying to achieve basically i have 2 listboxes next to each other, one for each of the xmls. Once i compare them i want both listboxes populated with all the file names but not the hashcodes and then to mark them in different colors depending if they are the same file, same file but different content or the file does not exist at all in the other XML.)

I'm struggling to find a way to store the file names and their hash codes.

Code(I am using a C++ Dll i created to do some of the work):

```
 private String[] ProjOne()
        {
            //Intialize the functions in the DLL
            DllTest.Funtions Functions = new DllTest.Funtions();

            //Set the location where the XMLs can be found
            String Directory = "C:\\Users\\brandonm\\Desktop\\Backup\\XML\\";

            //Get and set the number of items in the directory
            int NumFiles = Functions.GetNumFiles(Directory);

            //Create a search string to be used to determine the fullpath name of the file
            //selected from the combobox
            String SelectedFile = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            String SearchString = "*" + SelectedFile + "*.XML";

            //Get and set the TC that will be used to get the filenames and hashcodes
            int SelectedTC = int.Parse(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());

            //Get and set an array containing a full path structure to the item selected from
            //the combobox using the search string created earlier. Get files returns an array
            //thus needs to be stored in an array
            String[] FullPaths = new String[NumFiles];
            FullPaths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\brandonm\\Desktop\\Backup\\XML", SearchString, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            int number = FullPaths.GetLength(0);

            // The number of items in the XML ie. Number of Filenames in a particular TC
            int NumXMLItems = NumXMLItemsListOne();

            // Initialize the array that will hold the Filenames and their equivalent Hashcodes
            String[] FileNames = new String[NumXMLItems];
            String[] HashCode = new String[NumXMLItems];
            String[,] ProjectOne = new String[HashCode.Length, HashCode.Length];

            //Itteration through the all the XMLs in the location to add the current items into their arrays
            for (int x = 0; x < NumFiles; x++)
            {
                String FullPath = FullPaths[x];

                XPathNavigator Root = new XPathDocument(FullPath).CreateNavigator();

                foreach (XPathNavigator Cycle in Root.Select(String.Format(@"//TestCycle[@Number = '{0}']", SelectedTC)))
                {
                    foreach (XPathNavigator Nav in Cycle.Select(@"Files/FileName/@File"))
                    {
                        int y = 0;
                        FileNames[y] = Nav.Value;
                        y = y + 1;
                    }
                    foreach (XPathNavigator Nav in Cycle.Select(@"Files/HashCode/@Code"))
                    {
                        int z = 0;
                        HashCode[z] = Nav.Value;
                        z = z + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            return FileNames;
        }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Projects>
  <Project Name="tfasdtyf">
    <TestCycle Number="2387468">
      <Files>
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\DllTest.dll" />
        <HashCode Code="0E-C5-03-AD-CC-21-62-49-D9-36-3F-C4-F1-17-BC-11" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\WpfDllTest.exe" />
        <HashCode Code="60-46-A3-6F-82-E4-0A-00-2A-60-83-47-B2-16-F3-24" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\WpfDllTest.vshost.exe" />
        <HashCode Code="76-7B-6F-37-0D-3A-F2-F4-32-D1-70-A5-75-3B-DE-95" />
      </Files>
    </TestCycle>
  </Project>
  <Project Name="tfasdtyf">
    <TestCycle Number="23423">
      <Files>
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\DllTest.dll" />
        <HashCode Code="0E-C5-03-AD-CC-21-62-49-D9-36-3F-C4-F1-17-BC-11" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\WpfDllTest.exe" />
        <HashCode Code="60-46-A3-6F-82-E4-0A-00-2A-60-83-47-B2-16-F3-24" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\WpfDllTest.vshost.exe" />
        <HashCode Code="76-7B-6F-37-0D-3A-F2-F4-32-D1-70-A5-75-3B-DE-95" />
      </Files>
    </TestCycle>
  </Project>
  <Project Name="tfasdtyf">
    <TestCycle Number="1112">
      <Files>
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\DllTest.dll" />
        <HashCode Code="0E-C5-03-AD-CC-21-62-49-D9-36-3F-C4-F1-17-BC-11" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\WpfDllTest.exe" />
        <HashCode Code="60-46-A3-6F-82-E4-0A-00-2A-60-83-47-B2-16-F3-24" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\WpfDllTest.vshost.exe" />
        <HashCode Code="76-7B-6F-37-0D-3A-F2-F4-32-D1-70-A5-75-3B-DE-95" />
      </Files>
    </TestCycle>
  </Project>
  <Project Name="tfasdtyf">
    <TestCycle Number="999">
      <Files>
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\DllTest.dll" />
        <HashCode Code="0E-C5-03-AD-CC-21-62-49-D9-36-3F-C4-F1-17-BC-11" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\WpfDllTest.exe" />
        <HashCode Code="60-46-A3-6F-82-E4-0A-00-2A-60-83-47-B2-16-F3-24" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\WpfDllTest.vshost.exe" />
        <HashCode Code="76-7B-6F-37-0D-3A-F2-F4-32-D1-70-A5-75-3B-DE-95" />
      </Files>
    </TestCycle>
  </Project>
  <Project Name="tfasdtyf">
    <TestCycle Number="34534">
      <Files>
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\DllTest.dll" />
        <HashCode Code="0E-C5-03-AD-CC-21-62-49-D9-36-3F-C4-F1-17-BC-11" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\WpfDllTest.exe" />
        <HashCode Code="60-46-A3-6F-82-E4-0A-00-2A-60-83-47-B2-16-F3-24" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\WpfDllTest.vshost.exe" />
        <HashCode Code="76-7B-6F-37-0D-3A-F2-F4-32-D1-70-A5-75-3B-DE-95" />
      </Files>
    </TestCycle>
  </Project>
  <Project Name="Music">
    <TestCycle Number="12312">
      <Files>
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Desktop\Stuff\Dubstep\01 A1 Shut Ya Mouth.mp3" />
        <HashCode Code="3E-92-80-93-D5-64-19-16-26-8D-39-2A-C7-0B-C8-EB" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Desktop\Stuff\Dubstep\01 A1 Snake Eater.mp3" />
        <HashCode Code="8B-DF-19-AE-87-52-64-2E-85-CF-57-4B-85-4D-CC-E9" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Desktop\Stuff\Dubstep\01 A1 Stuck in the System.mp3" />
        <HashCode Code="6A-30-A7-53-FF-29-A5-DF-6D-24-DF-41-74-EE-06-4D" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Desktop\Stuff\Dubstep\01 Martin Solveig - Hello (Featuring Dragonette).mp3" />
        <HashCode Code="93-90-A3-9C-BE-81-63-03-D7-96-1F-72-E4-ED-2D-32" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Desktop\Stuff\Dubstep\01 Stimming - Funkworm.mp3" />
        <HashCode Code="8F-E1-7A-F1-B7-80-C6-2F-DC-34-FD-82-A0-DA-35-5E" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Desktop\Stuff\Dubstep\1. Downlink - Ignition.mp3" />
        <HashCode Code="3D-89-B3-C2-73-A6-A0-85-02-C0-B4-F9-C8-09-14-C7" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Desktop\Stuff\Dubstep\02 B1 Psychedelic Runway.mp3" />
        <HashCode Code="00-72-5C-CE-25-73-98-31-69-71-68-48-31-A1-A3-5A" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Desktop\Stuff\Dubstep\02 B1 Rapture.mp3" />
        <HashCode Code="1E-A6-53-07-10-FD-A3-4C-EF-D6-92-7F-CE-97-88-6E" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Desktop\Stuff\Dubstep\02_Digital-Controller.mp3" />
        <HashCode Code="94-E0-CA-5F-2B-D2-56-7B-AF-2E-04-50-58-38-4D-B4" />
        <FileName File="C:\Users\brandonm\Desktop\Stuff\Dubstep\2. Downlink - Gamma Ray.mp3" />
        <HashCode Code="3C-7A-76-AD-A6-2C-D1-7E-61-24-C0-40-BD-A7-A9-41" />
      </Files>
    </TestCycle>
  </Project>
</Projects>
```

I currently have another function identical to the one above so one for each listbox the only difference is the file and the testcyle number which determines where in the XML they will retrieve their files and hash codes. They store them in 4 separate arrays, 2 arrays per function. But obviously my function cannot return two arrays so it is currently only return the one.

2D arrays confuse me a lot and im not sure how i would get the information i need out of them when it comes down to the comparing i need to do. Can anyone direct me to a better way of doing this?

I dont want to really make 4 functions like the one above for the each set of filenames and then each set of hashcodes. But i'm still a beginner so maybe that is my best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's better not to duplicate the function**.  You want to make a single function that can be used in all of your cases here.

As for storing the filenames and hashcodes, .NET has a lot of useful collection classes you can use.  For example, you could use a `Dictionary<string, string>` like this:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < NumFiles; i++)
        {
            dictionary.Add(FileNames[i], HashCode[i]);
        }
```

The above code you could put right before your return statement in the function you provided.  Then return the dictionary.  Of course, you could make the entire function shorter by storing them directly in the dictionary, but I'll leave that for you to decide.

Now, wherever this function is called from, you might need to loop through this dictionary.  Here's a way to do that:

```
        foreach (var pair in dictionary)
        {
            string filename = pair.Key;
            string hashcode = pair.Value;

            // Do whatever you want with them here
        }
```

No doubt there are other ways to do what you want.  I am not completely sure what your overall goal is.  You should experiment with other generic collections too, such as `List<T>`.

Comment: Thanks Philip. My application is suppose to identify if a file has changed or been altered, doing this by comparing the 2 files hashcodes. I'm a tester so every Test cycle we get released files that may have changed but there may have been background changes or the baseline may have changed between TC's. So the comparison needs to be between filenames, if the files are the same check the hashcode and mark them green if the files are the same, orange if its a new file, red if the file exists but the hash is different. I give this a try and feedback if it helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

If HashCode belongs to a File, why isn't it a sub-element/attribute of it? It would make it way easier to parse.

Since you create the file, I'd create the structure like:

```
<Project Name="tfasdtyf">
    <TestCycle Number="23423">
      <Files>
        <File Name="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\DllTest.dll" HashCode="0E-C5-03-AD-CC-21-62-49-D9-36-3F-C4-F1-17-BC-11" />
        <File Name="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\WpfDllTest.exe" HashCode="60-46-A3-6F-82-E4-0A-00-2A-60-83-47-B2-16-F3-24" />
        <File Name="C:\Users\brandonm\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WpfDllTest\WpfDllTest\bin\x86\Release\WpfDllTest.vshost.exe" HashCode="76-7B-6F-37-0D-3A-F2-F4-32-D1-70-A5-75-3B-DE-95" />
      </Files>
    </TestCycle>
</Project>
```

Then with some XElement magic, you could use:

```
public class Project
{
    XElement self;
    public Project(XElement project)
    {
        self = project;
    }

    public TestCycle TestCycle
    {
        get 
        { 
            // If there are more than one TestCycle per project, you may end 
            // up creating something similar to TestCycle.Files (see TestCycle class below)

            XElement testCycle = self.Element("TestCycle");
            if(null == testCycle)
                self.Add(testCycle = new XElement("TestCycle"));
            return new TestCycle(testCycle);
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
         get { return return self.GetString("Name", string.Empty, ATTRIBUTE); }
         set { self.Set("Name", value, ATTRIBUTE); } // see Set Extension method below
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Project> Load(string filename)
    {
         return XElement.Load(filename)).Elements("Project").Select(xp => new Project(xp));
    }
}

public class TestCycle
{
    XElement self;
    public TestCycle(XElement testCycle)
    {
        self = testCycle;
    }

    private XElement XFiles
    {
        get 
        {
            XElement files = self.Element("Files");
            if(null == files)
                self.Add(files = new XElement("Files"));
            return files;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<FileHash> Files
    {
        get 
        {
            return XFiles.Elements("File").Select(xf => new FileHash(xf));
        }
    }

    public int Number
    {
         get { return self.GetInt("Number", 0, ATTRIBUTE); }
         set { self.Set("Number", value, ATTRIBUTE); } // see Set Extension method below
    }

    public FileHash AddFile(string name, string hashCode)
    {
         FileHash file = Files.FirstOrDefault(xf => xf.Name == name);
         if(null != file)
             file.self.Remove(); // replacing (but could throw an exception saying already exists instead)
         XElement xFile = new XElement("File");
         self.Add(xFile);
         file = new FileHash(xFile)
         {
             Name = name,
             HashCode = hashCode
         };
         return file;
    }
}

public class FileHash
{
    internal XElement self;
    public FileHash(XElement fileHash)
    {
        self = fileHash;
    }

    public string Name
    {
         get { return self.GetString("Name", string.Empty, ATTRIBUTE); }
         set { self.Set("Name", value, ATTRIBUTE); } // see Set Extension method below
    }

    public string HashCode
    {                 
         get { return return self.GetString("HashCode", string.Empty, ATTRIBUTE); }
         set { self.Set("HashCode", value, ATTRIBUTE); } // see Set Extension method below
    }
}
```

Extension methods:

```
public static XElementExtensions
{
    public const bool ATTRIBUTE = true;
    public const bool ELEMENT = false;
    public const bool? BOTH = null;

public void Set(this XElement self, string name, object value, bool isAttribute)
{
    string sValue = value.ToString();
    XElement eValue = self.Element(name);
    XAttribute aValue = self.Attribute(name);
    if(null != eValue)
        eValue.ReplaceWith(new XElement(name, sValue));
    else if(null != aValue)
        aValue.ReplaceWith(new XAttribute(name, sValue));
    else if(isAttribute)
        self.Add(new XAttribute(name, sValue));
    else
        self.Add(new XElement(name, sValue));
}

public string GetString(this XElement self, string name, string @default, bool? isAttribute)
{
    XAttribute aValue = self.Attribute(name);
    XElement eValue = self.Element(name);
    if(null == isAttribute) // try both
    {
        if(null != aValue) return (string)aValue;
        if(null != eValue) return (string)eValue;
        return @default;
    }
    if(isAttribute && null != aValue)
        return (string)aValue;
    if(!isAttribute && null != eValue)
        return (string)eValue);
    return @default;
}

public int GetInt(this XElement self, string name, int @default, bool? isAttribute)
{
    return Convert
        .ToInt32(GetString(self, name, null, isAttribute) ?? @default.ToString());
}

}
```

Then you can use the code like:

```
Project[] projects = Project.Load(filename).ToArray();

foreach(Project project in projects)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Project: " + project.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("TestCycle: " + project.TestCycle.Number.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Files:");
    foreach(FileHash file in project.TestCycle.Files)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("    Name: {0}, HashCode: {1}", file.Name, file.HashCode));
}
```

Or for your application, to compare two xml files:

```
var fileA = Project.Load(fileAname);
var fileB = Project.Load(fileBname);
```

I'm not quite sure how you mean, all the files, but I'll attempt it.

```
File[] filesA = fileA.SelectMany(project => project.TestCycle.Files).ToArray();
File[] filesB = fileB.SelectMany(project => project.TestCycle.Files).ToArray();
```

Using these Extension Methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>
(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second,
    Func<TSource, TSource, bool> comparer
)
{
    return first.Except(second, new LambdaComparer<TSource>(comparer));
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>
(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second,
    Func<TSource, TSource, bool> comparer
)
{
    return first.Intersect(second, new LambdaComparer<TSource>(comparer));
}
```

And the LambdaComparer class:

```
public class LambdaComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T, bool> equals;
    private readonly Func<T, int> getHashCode;

    public LambdaComparer(Func<T, T, bool> lambdaComparer) :
        this(lambdaComparer, o => o.GetHashCode())
    {
    }

    public LambdaComparer(Func<T, T, bool> lambdaComparer, Func<T, int> lambdaHash)
    {
        if (lambdaComparer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lambdaComparer");
        if (lambdaHash == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lambdaHash");

        equals = lambdaComparer;

        getHashCode = lambdaHash;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return equals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return getHashCode(obj);
    }
}

File[] filesInA_butNotInB = filesA.Except(filesB, (a,b) => a.Name == b.Name).ToArray();
File[] filesInBoth = filesA.Intersect(filesB, (a,b) => a.Name == b.Name).ToArray();
File[] filesInBoth_butDifferentHash = FilesA.Intersect(filesB, (a,b) => a.Name == b.Name && a.HashCode != b.HashCode).ToArray();
```

**That should "get you started" ...**

PS: I wrote (most of) this all by hand, not via compiler so there are probably some typo's that the compiler will catch.

PS: Also, all the `.ToArray()'s` are just because `File[]` is easier to read than `IEnumerable<File>`.  It is easier to read but about the same typing either way.

PSS: I hope you find this useful.  I love the Xml Linq way of handling things, so it was **fun** writing this out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer chuck :) this is a bit beyond my level haha but ill do some research into some of the things you've used since ive never seen lambda before. i will give it a try though it might solve alot of my issues.

Comment: Also thanks for the comment on sub element/attributes i didnt know that was possible. I may be limited by it though since im using XMLDocument in C++/CLI to create the XML and im then calling the function through a DLL. Didnt it this way as i had already coded it before i began using C#