# Xml Adding removing and manipulating data

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having trouble with xml integrated with c#, using a UI, I can create the document the way I need it including save/load/display functions, what I'm lacking is the ability to reload and existing xml file "Books.xml" to add or remove an entry and save it with the same name. my code is:

```
    XmlTextWriter Writer = new XmlTextWriter ("NewDoc.xml", Encoding.UTF8);

    Writer.WriteStartDocument();

    Writer.WriteStartElement("SAVED");

    Writer.WriteStartElement("TITLE");
    Writer.WriteString(textBox2.Text);
    Writer.WriteEndElement();//TITLE

    foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        Writer.WriteStartElement("ITEM");
        Writer.WriteString(item);
        Writer.WriteEndElement();//ITEM
    }

    Writer.WriteEndElement();//SAVED

    Writer.WriteEndDocument();

    Writer.Close();
```

I know I'm probably not being very clear here but I'm a complete novice and I've only been doing it for 3 months now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Books>
  <ID1>
    <TITLE>Harry Potter
</TITLE>
    <AUTHOR>JK Rowling
</AUTHOR>
    <PUBLISHED>1995 
</PUBLISHED>
    <PUBLISHERS>Bloomberg,
</PUBLISHERS>
  </ID1>
  <ID2>
    <TITLE>Disc World
</TITLE>
    <AUTHOR>Terry Pratchet
</AUTHOR>
    <PUBLISHED>1990
</PUBLISHED>
    <PUBLISHERS>ETC
</PUBLISHERS>
  </ID2>
  <ID3>
    <TITLE>IT
</TITLE>
    <AUTHOR>Stephen King
</AUTHOR>
    <PUBLISHED>1999
</PUBLISHED>
    <PUBLISHERS>ETC
</PUBLISHERS>
  </ID3>
</Books>
```

This is the xml code.

Comment: Hi Jim, what version of .NET are you using?

Comment: As far as I'm aware its .NET 4

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at the `XDocument` class, which makes it much easier to work with XML files.  It's hard to give a sample without the XML, but take a look at this answer for some idea of how this is done:

[Easiest way to add xml a node with a bunch of children nodes in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993665/easiest-way-to-add-xml-a-node-with-a-bunch-of-children-nodes-in-net/7993767#7993767)

If you post some sample XML we can come up with some code for you.  The basic idea is that you use `XDocument.Load(filename)` and then `XElement.Add(...)` to insert new elements.

**Update**
This code will load your XML from a file, add some elements, and save to a different file.  It may not be exactly the XML you are trying to add, but should be enough to get you going.  You can also save back to the original file if you want (I save to foo2.xml so I didn't overwrite my test file).

You can see I replaced listbox1.Items with a string array -- you should be able to swap those lines and get what you want.

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\temp\foo.xml");
        var itemsToAdd = new[] { "item1", "item2", "item3" };
        // var itemsToAdd = listBox1.Items;
        xdoc.Root.Add(
            new XElement("SAVED",
                new XElement("TITLE",
                    itemsToAdd.Select(e => new XElement(e)))));
        xdoc.Save(@"c:\temp\foo2.xml");
    }
```

Comment: Sorry if this looks a little messy, I had to indent it like this in order to get it to display properly in a richtextbox, you code looks good from the previous answer but I have no idea how to get it to work for me, I'm using multiple forms although I don't actually have to. Thats not how it actually looks and I'm getting frustrated at this site lol.

Comment: No problem, it would be helpful if you could post the expected XML output too (I just guessed)

Comment: Sorry for sounding fussy but that doesn't really help, I'm a complete novice to anything c# and without holding my hand I'm finding it hard to get anywhere with this.

Comment: If you could edit your question above to have what the XML looks like before, and what you want it to look like after, I will be able to help you more.

Comment: Its ok thanks, I've decided to struggle like hell with SQL instead, it seems to be more aligned to my needs, thankyou for all the help buddy.

Answer (score 0):

C# is an Object Oriented Language, you will find that breaking your problem into smaller pieces (class, properties and methods) helpful.

I refer you to two answers to questions I answered like yours that I explain this approach.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5609126/353147

The second may be over your head just 3 months into C#, but have a look if you want:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802442/353147

The class approach is handy, easy to manipulate values and read/write to file quickly.

I'd create two classes for your approach (Books and Book).  The Books class would read/write to file and contain the list of books and the ability add/subtract books from the list.

The only difficulty I see is having a different tag name for each book, but that isn't a huge hurtle, just more difficult.

If your book tag could be changed from `<ID1>` to `<Book ID="1">` that would make it simpler, then you could manipulate the list of Book tags quickly (as it comes already implemented in Linq).

I don't have the time right now to write a complete example, but if you find the two links interesting and would like to see an example, I can write one later.  Leave a comment to that affect here.