# How to add data to a larger XML file using VB

Tags: xml, vb.net

New to the forum, hope someone is able to help.  I've been Googling this and trying different ways for 2 days now.

I have a larger XML file, I want to add data records deep withing the file. The path to where i want to add it is:

//Content/Catalog/Feature[@code="K65000400"]/Option

I want to add more records to "Options". Currently there is a list of 68 options each with "code" and "DisplayName" elements.

All the examples I found only showed how to add records off the root.

If anyone understands what I am saying and can help, sure would appreciate it!

Using VB (VS2015) by the way.

Thanks,
-Kurt

NEW DETAILS :

Here is a link to the full xml file: [link](http://kwhdesign.ca/Temp/paf.xml)

The section I wand to add is :

```
<Option code="TEST">
<DisplayName lang="en-US"><![CDATA[Test Description]]</DisplayName>
<Multimedia type="MediumImage">    
<[CDATA[Multimedia\Pictures\Medium\TestMed.jpg]]></Multimedia>
<Multimedia type="LargeImage">   
<[CDATA[Multimedia\Pictures\Large\TestLarge.jpg]]></Multimedia>
<CustomData>
<![CDATA[<xml><RECKEY code="010201650004001V" /></xml>]]></CustomData>
</Option>
```

the  section is located here:

/Content/Catalog/Feature[7]    (Option[69])

Hope this helps.  I use XMLSpy to view xml data so I look at the file using a "grid" view which I find easier to read.  So I am not as good with the raw xml text, I hope I've explained sufficiently.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xml Adding removing and manipulating data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356692/xml-adding-removing-and-manipulating-data)

Comment: Show some of the file, particularly the beginning, end and where the new data goes and what the new data looks like,

Comment: I updated the original message to include the download link and what I am trying to add to the file.

Comment: I tried the "Xml Adding removing and manipulating data" but I could not get it to work with my data.  Rather than add a new row of data to the "\Content\Catalog\Feature[@code='K65000400']\Option" node it would duplicate the "Option" node in the "\Content\Catalog\Feature[@code='K65000400']" node.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Consider running XSLT. While I do not know VB.Net, like most general purpose languages (C#, Java, PHP, Python), XSLT 1.0 processors are available. VB.Net can possibly use the [XSLTransform](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307322) like C# or use [DOMDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765520(v=vs.85).aspx) like VBA (of which I have done quite a bit in MS Access/Excel).

As information, [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) is a special purpose language used to transform XML documents. Its script is a well-formed XML file so can be read in from file or from string. Below XSLT runs the Identity Transform to copy document as is and then applies a template to specific location adding needed new Options.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl to be loaded in VB or load as string)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- RETAIN XML MARKUP INSIDE CDATA -->
  <xsl:template match="CustomData">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>  
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>  

  <!-- ADDS NEW OPTIONS TO SPECIFIC NODE -->
  <xsl:template match="Feature[@code='K65000400']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="DisplayName|Description|Multimedia|Option|CustomData"/>
      <Option code="TEST">
        <DisplayName lang="en-US">Test Description</DisplayName>
        <Multimedia type="MediumImage">Multimedia\Pictures\Medium\TestMed.jpg</Multimedia>
        <Multimedia type="LargeImage">Multimedia\Pictures\Large\TestLarge.jpg</Multimedia>
        <CustomData>
           <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
              <xml><RECKEY code="010201650004001V" /></xml>
           <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>    
        </CustomData>
      </Option>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="FeatureSubset"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**VB** *(borrowed from [MSDN Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762785(v=vs.85).aspx))*

```vb
Private Function CreateDOM()
    Dim dom
    Set dom = New DOMDocument60
    dom.async = False
    dom.validateOnParse = False
    dom.resolveExternals = False
    Set CreateDOM = dom
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim doc, xsl, out

    Set doc = CreateDOM
    doc.Load "C:\Path\To\Input.xml"

    Set xsl = CreateDOM
    xsl.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLTScript.xsl"

    Set out = CreateDOM
    doc.transformNodeToObject xsl, out

    out.Save "C:\Path\To\Output.xml" 
End Sub
```

Comment: The XSLT didn't seem to work.  It seem to un-format part of the XML file.  Odd?  I edited my post and added a link to download the XML file if you are interested in trying yourself, maybe the code can be tweaked? Thanks much for your help.

Comment: See updated XSLT script. Also, no need to wrap `<!CData` if not escaping XML markup like the embedded `<xml>` (a special node name).

Comment: This didn't work, it may be I my explanation as to where I am trying to add data.  Under the Content/Catalog/Feature[K65000400] there is an Options node which has 68 entries.  I am wanting to add a 69th entry (code, DisplayName,Multimedia & CustomData). When I ran your code the Feature[K65000400] Node disappears and the formatting of the entire file is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems my problem was when adding an "XElement" I should use Xelement.AddAfterSelf rather than Xelement.Add
Strange, but it's working now.